# Variable for a right-clicked item (say, a jpg) in a bash script?

Tags: bash, right-click

I have a very simple bash script that I run often from the cli, but I've found it's frustrating to have to open a terminal, identify the right file, and run it and think the easiest way would be to run it as an option from a right-click.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The script is just erasing exif data, leaving the orientation tags, essentially this:

```
exiftool -all= -tagsfromfile @ -Orientation file-*.jpg
```

Is there a way to have the script identify which image I'm right clicking on?  I'm at a loss what to put in the file-*.jpg part which will be a variable for "whatever image I'm right-clicking on right now."

Tried searching for a good while on how to do this but am clearly either not using the right search terms or else this isn't done very often.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Perhaps include some details of your Operating System and User-interface.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, @Kingsley!  I added my OS.  I'm not sure what the User Interface is.  X?

Comment: This isn't what you were asking for, but you could try `exiftool ... $(zenity --file-selection)`. It doesn't add right-click selection to the regular file browser, but it does let you use the file browser component to select a file.

Comment: Thank you, @jamieguinan, I can do the right-click context menu part already, but I think you've answered what I was trying to find out...how to make the variable equal "whatever file I've right clicked on"  Fingers crossed.  If this works, can you reword it as a answer so I can click it as correct?  Tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the question is a little older, but I can provide you with the solution.

You have to set up `FileManager-actions`, an extension for GNOME/Nautilus (but it also works for other file managers).

### Setup filemanager-actions on Ubuntu 20.04

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install filemanager-actions
```

Then run `fma-config-tool` and create a new action.

When creating an action, please ensure that:

- [v] Display item in selection context menu

is flagged; otherwise, you will not see the context menu during the file selection.

[image: FMA-action-config]

### Prepare the script you want to execute

Prepare a script that does what you need. Touch in `/tmp`, `mv` it in `/usr/bin` and give it execute permissions:

```sh
touch /tmp/your-script
# edit it with your editor
sudo mv /tmp/your-script /usr/bin/
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/your-script
```

In your script, you can reference the filename using `$1`.

```
FILENAME=$1
echo $FILENAME
```

In the variable `FILENAME` you will find the selected file name.

### Configure Nautilus-action command

To let nautilus pass the filename, insert the script path and the argument string in the' command' tab.

[image: FMA-action-command]

To fully answer your question, to let Nautilus pass the filename as a script argument, you have to specify `%f`.

At this point, quit the Nautilus instance and open it again:

```sh
nautilus -q
nautilus
```

Now, let's have a try! Right-click on a file and check out the result!

### Appendix 1 - Filemanager-actions formats

- `%f` A single file name, even if multiple files are selected.
- `%F` A list of files. Each file is passed as a separate argument to the executable program.
- `%u` A single URL. Local files may either be passed as file: URLs or as file path.
- `%U` A list of URLs. Each URL is passed as a separate argument to the executable program.
- `%d` Base directory

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/783313/940068) you can find a comprehensive list.

### Appendix 2 - Sources

- Check out my post blog in which I actually realize something similar: https://gabrieleserra.ml/blog/2021-08-14-filemanager-actions-ubuntu-20-04.html
- Reference to all possible formats for FileManager-actions: https://askubuntu.com/a/783313/940068
- Realize it in Ubuntu 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/77285/940068

Comment: This works!  Thank you for the clear explanation and step-by-step.  My only missing link was that the option didn't appear until I completely logged out and logged back in again.  After that...perfect!  So happy to have this functionality again!

Comment: One additional follow up.  In the description above, it seemed like using %F (rather than %f) will allow me to select multiple files at the same time and have the script run on those.  However, I'm only getting one...whether I select one file or multiples.  Is there a way to extend this to a number of selected files or am I only going to be able to do this one at a time?

Comment: I have to try, but I think using `%F` filenames are passed in arguments. Hence, when you select more than 1 file and you want to access, for instance, to the second filename, you have to use `$2`, `$3` for the third and so on. Then, `$#` contains the number of arguments (or filenames in this particular case) given to the script.

Comment: My script is just a one line exif remover using exiftool that strips the info and saves the file in a folder.  I'm using $1 in the script, but maybe the solution would be to have the script be a loop?  If it were something like "while %F, then (do something here, $1, $2, $3, etc.)?   My script is maybe the issue?  It is only set to run once, for one lone file?  
I guess I'm not really understanding how %f and %F differ. Both work in my script, but only for one image at a time.  At this point, I am basically set. Really, this is more a tweak, to understand. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Would I be able to use:

while $#
do
script here
done

Which variable will work for looping through the selected files?

Comment: Yes, I have still to try but I believe the way `%f` and `%F` differ is only the number of supported filenames. Therefore using `%f` you can get only the first selected file using `$1` in your bash script while using `%F` you can get all selected filenames using `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on. For sure in your bash script you have to loop over arguments with something like
`for FILE in "$@"; do exiftool -all= -tagsfromfile @ -Orientation "$FILE"; done`

Comment: I think that did the trick!  I'm able to select multiples and it's working now!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Gabriele, it's been a while and I've realized that this works except when a filename has spaces in it.  Do you know by any chance how I might get it to treat the filename as a string and not an argument?  (I can rename files beforehand but it's tedious.)

Comment: Yes, I actually tried and seems it's enough to escape strings in the script. So, if you access to the file $1, you can use "$1". If you need help, send me your script I will try to fix it!

Answer (score 2):

if you want your script to run in file manager right-click menu you have to change your script and define file(s) as arguments. this happens simply by changing your file section with `$1` to `$n` as the parameter(s).

as far as I know ubuntu uses nautilus as an file manager.
you can run `nautilus-actions-config-tool` either from your terminal or from dash and define your script a name and a command to run. you can follow this link for illustration learning :
**[ubuntu nautilus defile script in menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus)**

for example :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    echo "Positional parameter 1 contains value $1"
else
    echo "Positional parameter 1 is empty"
fi
```

for all arguments :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; then

  for arg in "$@"; do

    echo $arg

  done

fi
```

[here is the image that shows the script worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Uak.png)

Comment: Hi Mahdi, can you explain the first part again?  I didn't use "$1" in my script above so I'm confused about what you're saying.  I already know about nautilus-actions-config-tool, that's not the problem.  Just I'm unclear how in a bash script to signify that the file (call it *.jpg) is the file that's being right clicked on.  

(Possibly this is what @jamieguinan is alerting me to...I'm going to check it out!)